# How to define variable "counter" to execute my calculator program correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am very sorry to ask a very simple question, however I need to solve it to execute my individual Python code correctly.

This code below is a calculator that can calculate addition subtraction multiplication division and save all the results in the past 10 calculations, and save into the first again if the number of calculations gets over 10 times.

But when I run this code, the error `NameError: name 'counter' is not defined` comes out.

I want any solution to solve this defining variable because this error occurs even though I am defining 'counter'.

```
def setup():
    answer0 = 0
    answer1 = 0
    answer2 = 0
    answer3 = 0
    answer4 = 0
    answer5 = 0
    answer6 = 0
    answer7 = 0
    answer8 = 0
    answer9 = 0
    counter = 1


    return answer0, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, counter

def decideprocess():
    global decision
    decision = str(input("Enter + for adding, - for subtracting, * for multiply, / for deviding, and 'all' for see what all calculation results so far. :"))

    return decision

def processes(decision, counter):
    decision = decideprocess()
    if decision == "+":
        addition(counter)
        decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "-":
    subtraction(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "*":
    multiplecation(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "/":
    devision(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "all":
    print(answer0)
    print(answer1)
    print(answer2)
    print(answer3)
    print(answer4)
    print(answer5)
    print(answer6)
    print(answer7)
    print(answer8)
    print(answer9)

    decideprocess()

    return answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, decision, result

def addition(counter):
    a = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    b = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    result = a + b
    print(result)
    counter = counter + 1
    assignment(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result)


    return counter ,result

def subtraction(counter):
    a = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    b = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    result = a - b
    print(result)
    counter = counter + 1
    assignment(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result)


    return counter ,result

def multiplecation(counter):
    a = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    b = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    result = a * b
    print(result)
    counter = counter + 1
    assignment(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result)


    return counter ,result

def devision(counter):
    a = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    b = float(input("Enter any number. :"))
    result = a / b
    print(result)
    counter = counter + 1
    assignment(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result)


    return counter ,result

def assignment(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result):
    while counter < 10:
        assignmentanswer(counter, result)
    if counter >= 10:
        changecountervalue(counter)
        assignmentanswerover10(result ,newcounter)

     return answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, result, newcounter

def assignmentanswer(counter, result):
    if counter == 1:
        answer0 = result
    if counter == 2:
        answer1 = result
    if counter == 3:
        answer2 = result
    if counter == 4:
        answer3 = result
    if counter == 5:
        answer4 = result
    if counter == 6:
        answer5 = result
    if counter == 7:
        answer6 = result
    if counter == 8:
        answer7 = result
    if counter == 9:
        answer8 = result
    if counter == 10:
        answer9 = result

    return counter, result

def changecountervalue(counter):
    counter10 = int(counter/10)
    newcounter = (counter10*10) - counter

    return newcounter

def assignmentanswerover10(newcounter, result):
    if newcounter == 1:
        answer0 = result
    if newcounter == 2:
        answer1 = result
    if newcounter == 3:
        answer2 = result
    if newcounter == 4:
        answer3 = result
    if newcounter == 5:
        answer4 = result
    if newcounter == 6:
        answer5 = result
    if newcounter == 7:
        answer6 = result
    if newcounter == 8:
        answer7 = result
    if newcounter == 9:
        answer8 = result
    if newcounter == 10:
        answer9 = result

    return newcounter, result

def showallresult(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10):
    print(answer0)
    print(answer1)
    print(answer2)
    print(answer3)
    print(answer4)
    print(answer5)
    print(answer6)
    print(answer7)
    print(answer8)
    print(answer9)

def calculator():
    setup()
    decideprocess()
    while decision == "+" or decision == "-" or decision == "*" or decision == "/" or decision == "all":
        processes(decision, counter)
    showallresult(answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10)

calculator()
```

Comment: Does the error message say which line of this program is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some code needs to be indented more.

Instead of this...

```py
def processes(decision, counter):
    decision = decideprocess()
    if decision == "+":
        addition(counter)
        decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "-":
    subtraction(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "*":
    multiplecation(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "/":
    devision(counter)
    decideprocess()

    return counter

elif decision == "all":
    print(answer0)
    print(answer1)
    print(answer2)
    print(answer3)
    print(answer4)
    print(answer5)
    print(answer6)
    print(answer7)
    print(answer8)
    print(answer9)

    decideprocess()

    return answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, decision, result
```

...try this:

```py
def processes(decision, counter):
    decision = decideprocess()
    if decision == "+":
        addition(counter)
        decideprocess()

        return counter

    elif decision == "-":
        subtraction(counter)
        decideprocess()

        return counter

    elif decision == "*":
        multiplecation(counter)
        decideprocess()

        return counter

    elif decision == "/":
        devision(counter)
        decideprocess()

        return counter

    elif decision == "all":
        print(answer0)
        print(answer1)
        print(answer2)
        print(answer3)
        print(answer4)
        print(answer5)
        print(answer6)
        print(answer7)
        print(answer8)
        print(answer9)

        decideprocess()

        return answe1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, counter, decision, result
```